# Get points in a union of circles

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to create a postgis query that would get all the points in an union of circles (possibly more than a thousand of circles with different radius). The circles would be created dynamically from a set of objects with a latitude, longitude and radius.

Is it possible to achieve this with postgis without perfomance issues?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? "Performance issues" is *very* subjective, so please edit the question to provide hard numbers on actual requirements.

Comment: Does the union need to be performed?  Can you check for a point that is in _any_ of the circles?

Comment: I just want to know if the point is in any of the circles but I don't care which one. But I avoid to perform too many queries to avoid performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Building the union of thousands of circles will be the expensive part. Actually finding the points inside the constructed object will be moderately fast, since the prepared geometry routines will kick in and you'll have an internally indexed query polygon. But building that polygon, could take a while.

```
WITH (
   query to build and union circles
) AS circles
SELECT pts.id
FROM pts JOIN circles ON ST_Contains(circles.geom, pts.geom)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ST_Buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb01X.png) which:

> Returns a geometry covering all points within a given distance from
>   the input geometry.

`ST_Buffer(your_geometry::geography, 7)` would output polygon of points with specified 7 meter radius.

[image]